# "considered to be" and "considered as"

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, sentence-usage, paraphrasing

This passage is from TOEFL:

> Those who are *considered to be* gorgeous can make millions of dollars
>   due to their looks, while musical geniuses with modest looks may
>   remain in obscurity.

I wonder if I can (or not) paraphrase **considered to be** into **considered as**.

Because I saw some **considered as** phrase in *Teentimes*; for example:

> "In some ways it is considered as a protective feature to prevent
>   terrorism."

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't say:

> Those who are considered as gorgeous...

and you should say something like:

> Those who are considered gorgeous / Those who are considered as gorgeous people

"Considered as" is **less common** than "considered to be" and they may have different meanings.

> He is considered to be a well-known professor.

This sentence means there are a lot of people who share the same idea about him.

> He is considered as a well-known professor.

In this sentence, it seems there is no evidence to see if he is really a famous professor (we may interpret "considered as" as "thought to be")

Finally, it's better to omit "as" and simply use "considered" (when you want to use considered as) according to [this context](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/as):

> As is sometimes used superfluously to introduce the complements of
>   verbs like consider, deem, and account, as in They considered it as
>   one of the landmark decisions of the civil rights movement. The
>   measure was deemed as unnecessary. This usage may have arisen by
>   analogy to regard and esteem, with which as is standardly used in this
>   way: We regarded her as the best writer among us. But the use of as
>   with verbs like consider is not sufficiently well established to be
>   acceptable in writing.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with *people considered as gorgeous*, though *considered gorgeous* is perhaps more popular, and used in different circumstances.